# How can I transfer media files from an Ubuntu PC to a Windows Phone?

Tags: usb, media, windows-phone

I am trying to copy media files from an Ubuntu computer to a Windows Phone (Lumia 520), but cannot get it to work. Instead, the device always behaves as a mass storage device and the media copied or transferred cannot be played on the phone, but can be transferred to any other OS or PC.

How can I add files to a Windows Phone from my Ubuntu PC in such a way that they can be played on the Windows Phone?

Answer (score 1):

I recently faced problems transferring files to my Lumia 620. I have three suggestions for you:

1. If you have a wifi connection available, just use the OneDrive linked to your Microsoft account. It has a pretty decent space of 15GB. Use this to transfer your files to the cloud and then download them on the phone.

   - The Windows Phone developers may want the user to adopt these wireless techniques instead or direct USB transfers. The Windows Phone Support page about file transfers from a PC is kind of indirect: “If, though, you still want to transfer files through USB...”.
2. Have you tried downloading the “File Manager” app (the official one from Microsoft Corporation) to your phone to browse these files in your phone’s storage?
3. Make sure your media files aren’t protected for copyright reasons and meant to be played only on one device. Try sending these files through a MTP client installed on your Ubuntu PC (Qlix or GMTP are available in the Ubuntu Software Center).

I hope one of these three ways works out for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the app Music Drop:
http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/music-drop/09a12ce5-26ec-4251-b7a1-16216de4c2fb

Works fine for me!

Comment: It needs a Microsoft account to download/install - I'd guess not many people here have them. I for one , don't.

Comment: @Parto If you have a Windows Phone (like in the question) you'll have a Microsoft account.